# Python json error list indices must be integers

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have json data:

```
[{
    "dataType": "detox",
    "hLogging": 0.5,
    "reading": 63.9,
    "minValue": 25,
    "dataValue": [{
        "time": 143221019,
        "value": 44
    }, {
        "time": 1433521119,
        "value": 66
    }, {
        "time": 1433521319,
        "value": 22
    }]
}, {
    "dataType": "epox",
    "hLogging": 3,
    "reading": 61.0,
    "min"Value: 0,
    "dataValue": [{
        "time": 1433521019,
        "value": 55
    }, {
        "time": 1433521119,
        "value": 66
    }, {
        "time": 1433521219,
        "value": 77
    }, {
        "time": 1433521319,
        "value": 88
    }]
}]
```

There are two `data types` which have their own `data value`. This `data value` contains `time` which is in unix epoch time. I need to convert it into normal date time value. For this I started by parsing the data using `for`:

```
for item in range(len(json_data['dataValue'])):
    print(json_data['dataValue'][item]['time'])
```

But this throws error:

```
string indices must be integers
```

Probably because json data has string values but then how can I approach to get the values of time and convert it into normal date time format. Also the time values are not fix in `datavalue`, it can be 3,4,5...nth items, so need to include range.  Please suggest a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json data which you have is not actually json data but the list having element as json data. So you have to call the index of the list before parsing the json data.

```
for item in range(len(json_data[0]['dataValue'])):
    print(json_data[0]['dataValue'][item]['time'])
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!